# Qt- Qlist checking contains with Custom class

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to override the comparing mechanism of Qt QList loaded with custom classes.

i.e In java you just have to override a compare method.

I am having a QList with my customclass model.

```
QList <CustomClass *>list;
CustomClass *c1=new CustomClass();
c1.name= "john";
list.append(c2); 
CustomClass *c2=new CustomClass();
c2.name= "john";

qDebug()<<list.contains(c2);  //false

//Secondly I have overridden the equals '==' operator and still getting false
qDebug()<< (c1 == c2); //false, why ? 
qDebug()<< (c1->operator ==(*c2)); //true

class CustomClass
{
QString name;
 bool operator==(const CustomClass& other)const
{
    if(this->name==(other.name))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
qDebug()<< (c1 == c2); //false, why ?
```

It is `false` because you are not comparing actual instances, but pointers.

Try this instead:

```
qDebug()<< (*c1 == *c2);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you'll need to store actual objects, not just pointers to them. In order to be able to store an object in a Qt container such as `QList`, the class must have the following:

- default constructor
- copy constructor
- assignment operator

In this case, the constructors and assignment operator implicitly generated by the compiler will suffice. If your class had e.g. pointer members, you'd need explicit copy/assignment to cover ownership issues.

For `QList::contains()` you can overload `operator==()` as you already have done.

For the second question, @Joachim Pileborg is correct.

Comment: One change , in my above post MyCustomClass does not inherit from QObject. When I inherit from QObject QList contains does not work. (Assuming my code above is same)

Comment: Yes, `QObject`-derived class instances cannot be used as values in containers. If you need to store `QObject`s, store pointers to them.