# How to make QList<Type*> work with indexOf() and custom operator==()?

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, qlist

Given the following code:

```
QList<Vertex*> _vertices; //this gets filled

//at some other point i want to check if there's already
//a vertex with the same payload inside the list
Vertex* v = new Vertex(payload);
int result = _vertices.indexOf(v);
if (result == -1){
    //add the vertex to the list
} else {
    //discard v and return pointer to match
}

//overloaded Vertex::operator==
bool Vertex::operator==(Vertex* other){
    //i return true if my payload and the others
    //payload are the same
}
```

As far as I can see indexOf() never ends up calling my operator==. I assume this is because of QList encapsulating a pointer type and indexOf() comparing the pointers. Is there a way of keeping ponters in the QList and still using my own operator==()?

Like `Vertex*::operator==(Vertex* other)`

Related Questions: [removing in pointer type Qlists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7539084/1387061) | [not working because of pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8924606/1387061)

**Edit**: Intention.

Two vertices are considered equal iff. identifiers carried by their payload are equal.

`Vertex` is part of a `Graph` class. I want clients of that class to be able to call `Graph::addEdge(Payload,Payload)` to populate the graph. Graph objects then take care of wrapping up Payloads in Vertex objects and building Edges. Hence Graph needs to check if a Vertex encapsulating a given payload doesn't already exist. Using QList seemed like the "simplest thing that might work" at the time of writing the code.

Comment: Can't you store 'QList<Vertex>' instead? Overloaded == won't work for pointers. And, actuall your code is not going to work: you construct **new** and try to lookup its **adress** in vector. Not going to succeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way of keeping ponters in the QList and still using my own
>   operator==()?

No, you would need QList to dereference the pointer first, which it doesn't.  You would have to subclass QList in order to do that.  But as `indexOf()` just iterates through and compares using `operator==()` there's nothing stopping you doing the same thing manually.

However, all of this looks like a code smell.  Trying to find something in an unordered/non-hashed container is in linear time - very slow compared to QMap/QHash.  Please edit your question describing *why* you want to do this, and what data `Vertex` contains, and we'll see if the community can up with better performing mechanism.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer @cbamber85 . The first part answers my question and provides solutions for the problem at hand. I agree about the code smell and did not consider runtime at the time of coding. I'll look into using a more appropriate container.